# Is this grammar correct: "It's infuriating no longer being able to tell them what I think of them."

Tags: grammaticality

So I have: "It's infuriating no longer being able to tell them what I think of them."
Is that grammatically correct?

I know I could use:
"It's infuriating that **I'm** no longer able to tell them what I think of them."
but is it really necessary to have that extra "**I**" at the start of the sentence?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first sentence at all. You sound like a native speaker.  For me: It's fun being able to suss that out. I might not write it but I might say it. For me: It's not fun not being able to tell you what I think. Speaking ain't writing.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I am a native speaker, and I can't speak anything else. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more grammatical to say, "It's infuriating *to no longer be able* to tell them what I think of them." No extra *I* necessary.

Comment: That's perfect! What I originally had sounded _off_, I knew there had to be a way to say it without the extra **I**.

Comment: Your assertion is simply not true.